# Countability with Disks?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I am oh so confused about how to prove things as countable or uncountable. Mainly the former.

We learned about it in lecture but I'm still lost.

Could someone explain how you'd say something is countable in an example like:

- Let's consider disks, 2d regions of the form ${(x, y) ∈ R^2 : (x−x_{0})^2 + (y−y_{0})^2 ≤ r^2}$ such that $x_{0}, y_{0}, r ∈ R$ . Say you have a set of disks none of which overlap. Is the set countable or could it be uncountable?

Comment: Pick one point with rational coordinates in each one of them. You will get an injective map from the collection of disks into a countable set.

Comment: wait im sorry i dont get what you mean by "in each of them"? and injective map?